# Dynamic Option does not trigger the Select Component in SolidJS. (Playground includes)

Tags: material-ui, signals, solid-js, suid

I am using SolidJS and SUID ( Solid material UI ) library.

I am trying to use the same example as in the SUID documentation.

https://suid.io/components/select

```
import { For, createResource, createSignal } from 'solid-js';
import { Select, MenuItem } from '@suid/material'; // or "solid-ui", based on the library's exports

function Post() {
  const [postsResource, { mutate, refetch }] = createResource(async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
    }
    return response.json();
  });

  // State for the selected option
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = createSignal('any');

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Posts</h1>
      {postsResource.loading && <p>Loading...</p>}
      {postsResource.error && <p>Error: {postsResource.error.message}</p>}
      {
        <>
          <Select
            // defaultValue={'any'}
            // value={selectedOption()}
            onChange={(e) => {
              console.log('onChange', e.currentTarget);
              setSelectedOption(e.currentTarget.value);
            }}
          >
            <MenuItem value="any">Choose any...</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="option1">option1</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="option2">option2</MenuItem>
            <For each={postsResource()}>
              {(post) => <MenuItem value={post.id}>{post.title}</MenuItem>}
            </For>
          </Select>
        </>
      }
    </div>
  );
}

export default Post;
```

In this case, the Options that have values like `any`, `option1` and `option2` (static options) are selectable, but other are not.

Also I should mention, when I use static options (code below) a Select works fine.

```
  const options = [
    {id: 1, label: 'Option 1'},
    {id: 2, label: 'Option 2'},
    {id: 3, label: 'Option 3'},
  ];
```

But when I use dynamic options (fetch, `createResource`, promise, etc), something goes wrong.
There are main problems:

1. Chosen Option does not change Select value
2. `onChange` handler always receives similar value
3. More than two Select changes cause console errors:

```
MUI: A component is changing the uncontrolled value state of Select to be controlled.
Elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa).
Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled Select element for the lifetime of the component.
The nature of the state is determined during the first render. It's considered controlled if the value is not `undefined`.
```

I tried to:

1. Set a `defaultValue` to `Select`;
2. Set a `defaultValue` to createSignal;
3. Set a `tabIndex`, because I noticed that in `For` each `MenuItem` has `tabIndex=-1`

[tabIndex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6tqZ.png)

---

#### Video/gif problem on [imgur](https://imgur.com/a/dhRc7CG)

#### SUID issue on [github](https://github.com/swordev/suid/issues/261)

---

#### Playground

Provide you with playground for your experiments.

- Original version [stackblitz1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/solidjs-templates-kxwzpx?file=src%2FApp.jsx)
- With Show & Props
  [stackblitz2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/solidjs-templates-hjjfdi?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FPost%2FPost.jsx)

---

What my expectations are:

- I should be able to choose any option from the Select

Answer (score 0):

The value from `createResource` will be `undefined` until the request resolves to a value. So,  the component `For` receives `undefined` initially. You should restructure your component accordingly. It is best to use Switch/Match with resource.state value for conditional rendering.

Edit: Problem is with how SUID handles event. Select implements controlled data flow that somehow does not work well reactive values.

Try using a static value like the index number, it works as expected. As soon as you use a reactive value, it emit errors.

```js
import { Match, Switch, createResource, createSignal } from 'solid-js';
import { Select, MenuItem } from '@suid/material';

function Post() {
  const [data, { mutate, refetch }] = createResource(async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
    }
    return response.json();
  });

  const [value, setValue] = createSignal('any');

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    setValue(event.target.value);
    console.log(event.currentTarget.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Posts {value()}</h1>
      <Switch>
        <Match when={data.state === 'pending'}>Loading</Match>
        <Match when={data.state === 'errored'}>Failed</Match>
        <Match when={data.state === 'ready'}>
          <Select
            labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
            id="demo-simple-select"
            value={value()}
            label="Value"
            onChange={handleChange}
          >
            {data().map((post, index) => (
              <MenuItem value={index}>{post.title}</MenuItem>
            ))}
          </Select>
        </Match>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Post;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I tried to follow you advice, but unfortunetly, it doesn't solve the issue.

I made video/gif with intermediate result.
Loaded it on **imgur** here
https://imgur.com/a/dhRc7CG.

Comment: It is how SUID handles reactive values. I would stay away from suid because it does not properly forward props, overwrites lots of things unnecessarily. It is not the first time, search the SO tags, it will return many similar issues.

Comment: What would you recommend as an alternative? 
I like material design and most of the other components work fine.
I would like to continue develop with SolidJS,  but want to use stable & reliable solutions

Comment: Thank you for your solution.
But it still is unstable and hard to control.
Why this line break everything?  
<MenuItem **value={post.id}**>
       {post.id}. {post.title}
</MenuItem>

Comment: Why not write your own components. The problem with these libraries is that they divide ui into many small and unnecessary subcomponents which quickly makes your app laggy.  Every component means at least two extra function calls. https://github.com/solidjs/solid/discussions/1399 They are full of problems because components do not properly extend built in elements, meaning you are allowed to use few props. For example, you can not use onclick with Input component because that prop is not forwarded to the <input> element. It'll take time but your app will be more performant.

Comment: I did not offer a solution because there is no easy solution, just diagnosed the problem. Suid uses controlled components, which is quite common in react but causes a lot headache in Solid. You can see this discussion to understand the difference between controlled and uncontrolled components: https://github.com/solidjs/solid/discussions/416